# ASPX JavaScript get element value by id

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to get value from ASPX element with JavaScript but getting

*`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` Error*.

This is HTML markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>Labour Cost:</td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lbllabourCost" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
```

And below is my JavaScript:

```
 <script>
    var labcost = document.getElementById('<%= lbllabourCost %>').value;
    console.log(labcost);
 </script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [`ClientID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which will resolve the client-side `id` attribute present for that control :

```
var labcost = document.getElementById('<%= lbllabourCost.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
```

Additionally, you may want to consider which property that you are targeting within Javascript (i.e. using `innerHTML` or `textContent` since you are targeting a label).

Comment: comes out as undefined

Comment: Did you try using the `innerHTML` or `textContent` properties?

Answer (score 0):

Probably two things.

First the ID to get the element in DOM and then to get the contents.

Try :

```
var labcost = document.getElementById('<%= lbllabourCost.ClientID %>').textContent;
```